# How to read &lt; as < from an XML?

Tags: java, xml

Perhaps this is a repeated question.

My requirement is to read following XML from a queue.

```
<Request>
    <ParameterValue><![CDATA[some text]]></ParameterValue>
  </Request>
```

When I read the XML, it looks like this:

```
 <Request>
     <ParameterValue>&lt;![CDATA[some text]]&gt;</ParameterValue>
  </Request>
```

When I read ParameterValue, it appears as `<![CDATA[some text]]>`. Where as I just want string: *some text*.

For my testing purpose if I push the XML into the queue like this:

```
amqsput PARAM.REQ MQM_NAME
<Request><ParameterValue><![CDATA[some text]]></ParameterValue></Request>
```

Then I am able to read *some text*.

But when an application pushes the same XML into queue. It appears with &lt and &gt characters.

Is there any way, I can handle these characters? I am using Java 7.

Should replace &lt and &gt with < and > before passing the string to XML parsing?

Comment: I'm confused. Which of the two XMLs are you actually reading? If you're supposed to be reading the first, then where does the second come from? Perhaps you need to tell whoever is giving you the XML to follow the requirement and actually give you the first XML and not the second. Or you need to change the requirement to say that you need to read the second.

Comment: I am getting the second XML. When I read it from a queue. Can I convert second XML to first XML (for this i am considering string replace function, before I start parsing it as XML)